# Massive patching - best approach

Tags: 2013, patching

Need to update SP2013 from SP1 to most recent build version.
Do I need to install all patches one by one (all dozens of them) or there's some shortcut?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have already installed SP 2013 SP1 , you can directly install the latest July 2017 Cumulative Update.

It includes all the previous updates and patches.

Reference - [CU for SP 2013](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3213569/july-11-2017-cumulative-update-for-sharepoint-server-2013-kb3213569)

Download link - [July 2017 CU for SP 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55625)

Recommended would be that you install the (N-1) i.e the June 2017 update. First do that on a test/staging environment and then move to production

You can directly download the file from the above link and then install it. Once done it might require a restart and then you will have to run the product configuration wizard.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! From my experience I'll get error message 'product not found' while trying to install CU with more then 3-6 month gap. But it was a while ago, maybe things changed or I've forgotten something... I'll give your solution a try this weekend

Comment: Got "The expected version of the product was not found on the system" on both June and Jule CU installation...

Comment: Check out this link - https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/06/14/the-expected-version-of-the-product-was-not-found-on-the-system-during-install-a-cumulative-update-in-sharepoint-2013/ , looks like we need to bypass package detection